# Div wont center on the screen unless I specify a height

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using the following jquery code to center a div on the page, the problem is it doesnt work unless I specify a height for the div in the css, the problem with this is that the div is supposed to resize by the content inside it. If I set height:auto in the css I still get the problem, but if I put height:300px for example it centers the div on the page then.

I have a jsfiddle of the problem here :
http://jsfiddle.net/Vjvyz/

Jquery

```
var positionContent = function () {
    var width = $(window).width(); // the window width
    var height = $(window).height(); // the window height
    var containerwidth = $('.container').outerWidth(); // the container div width
    var containerheight = $('.container').outerHeight(); // the container div height
    if ((width >= containerwidth) && (height>=containerheight)){
        $('.container').css({position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight())/2 }); 
    } 
};
//Call this when the window first loads
$(document).ready(positionContent);
//Call this whenever the window resizes.
$(window).bind('resize', positionContent);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menucontainer"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Passion stands for the enthusiasm and fervour we put into everything we do in the company, and in developing the right organisational mix to help others in every possible way<br />
        we want every guest to experience that passion for life by having the most relaxing, blissful and luxurious stay possible, a time filled with personal discovery, recovery and spiritual fulfillment.</p>
        <p>We want every employee to taste that passion for life by growing in confidence and skills, and feeling part of a close-knit global family.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width:300px; background:#eee; height:300px;}
```

Comment: use min-height: 300px; instead to specify a minimum height ... would this do the trick for you?

Comment: for what you using this <div class="container"></div> begining of html ?

Comment: Thanks Min height seems to do the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:table-cell`

```
.container {width:300px; background:#eee; display:table-cell}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjvyz/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use this code its worked across browser.

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.center = function()
    {
        var element = this;
        $(element).load(function()
        {
            changeCss();
            $(window).bind("resize", function()
            {
                changeCss();
            });
            function changeCss()
            {
                var imageHeight = $(element).height();
                var imageWidth = $(element).width();
                var windowWidth = $(window).width();
                var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                $(element).css({
                    "position" : "absolute",
                    "left" : windowWidth / 2 - imageWidth / 2,
                    "top" : windowHeight /2 - imageHeight / 2
                });
            };
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and then use it as `$('.container').center();`

Answer (score 1):

if you have a static height and width of your container you can do it with CSS only. than you could use the code below:

```
.container{
  width:300px; 
  background:#eee;
  height:300px;
  position:absolutel
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-150px; /* 50% of your width with the - */
  margin-top:-150px; /* 50% of your height with the - */
}
```

in your code you have

```
<div class="container"></div><div class='container'>
```

changing that to:

```
<div class='container'>
```

fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be it's a little bit hacky, but you can try that working with margins:

```
.container {margin-top:-25%;width:300px; background:#eee; height:inherit;position:relative;}
```